# Using React BrowserRouter (v4) how do I recognize when the location has changed?

Tags: react-router-v4

Have the following JSX

```
// Root.jsx
<BrowserRouter getUserConfirmation={this.handleLocationChange}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/' exact component={Search} />
                        <Route path='/queue/' component={Queue} />
                        <Route path='/healthCheck/' component={HealthCheck} />
                        <Route path='/transcript' component={Transcript} />
                    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>

// Root.js
export class Root extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    handleLocationChange(message, callback) {
        // your staff here
        console.log(`- - - location:`);
        callback(true);
    }
    render(){
        return RootTemplate.call(this);
    }
}
```

But when I run this I get...

```
Root.jsx:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleLocationChange' of undefined
    at RootTemplate (Root.jsx:25)
    at Root.render (Root.js:13)
```

If I try this...

```
getUserConfirmation={()=>this.handleLocationChange()}
```

I don't get an error but I also don't get my console like I would expect.

How do I tell when the location has changed?

**Update**

I also tried this just for testing...

```
const getConfirmation = (message, callback) => {
    console.log("Welp this is working");
    callback(true)
};
...
<BrowserRouter getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation}>
```

But still not seeing anything in the log.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the user has navigated to another page inside your application or navigating away from your application entirely?

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to check when a user has navigated from one location in your app to another you should use the history library. You can also use it for getUserConfirmation, which is when a user navigates away from your application.

```
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import { Router } from "react-router";

// Fires when user navigates away
const getUserConfirmation = () => console.log("User navigated away");

// Create your browser history
const history = createHistory({getUserConfirmation});

// Fires every time a location is updated
history.listen((location) => console.log("Navigated to page", location));

// Attach your browser history to your router
const MyRouter = () => <Router history={history> {your children} </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Prompt component from react-router. Include in one of you components.

Try doing this without using getUserConfirmation.

Prompt- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt